# can not run sqlplus commands in ssh connection

Tags: oracle, unix, virtual-machine, sqlplus

I connected to VM with ssh connection and I want to run sqlplus command, but when I run `sqlplus / as sysdba` (to example) I get `sqlplus: command not found`. 
I have on the VM oracle DB and I've created a data base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `sqlplus` binary in your PATH? Check your environment. Try:

```
which sqlplus
```

It should print the full path of the `sqlplus` command. If it doesn't, you must locate the binary an append the containing directory to your path or invoke the command by the full path.

Comment: I tried and I get /usr/bin/which: no sqlplus in (/home/oracle/scripts/showdb:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/oracle/bin)

Comment: Then sqlplus is NOT in your path! Find it, e.g. using find / -name sqlplus -print

Comment: Thanks, now I found it. what should I do now to run it?

Comment: Where did you find it? Let's say /oracle/bin/sqlplus. Then you can use the full path  /oracle/bin/sqlplus or edit your .bashrc and say PATH=$PATH:/oracle/bin; export PATH . Source your .bashrc or log in again and you should be able to launch sqlplus.

Comment: /home/oracle/orabase/product/11.2.0/bin/sqlplus   and i tried to run: /home/oracle/orabase/product/11.2.0/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba     and i received:      Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory

Comment: Add to your .bashrc : ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/orabase; export ORACLE_HOME. (i think the path is right). Again source .bashrc or log in (or read up on how a unix systems works)